# Not supported for select queries HIBERNATE+JAVA+HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Tengo un problema con un metodo de JAVA con hibernate y la query de HQL

El método lo que hace es recuperar un salario de un empleado sumarle un 20% y volver a insertarlo.

El código del método es el siguiente:

```
public void incrementarSueldo(){

    BigDecimal valorSubida = new BigDecimal("0.20");

    session = SessionFactoryUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("From Emp emp where emp.ename = :nombre");

    query.setParameter("nombre", "KING");

    Emp emp1 = (Emp) query.uniqueResult();

    BigDecimal oldSalary = emp1.getSal();

    BigDecimal porcentajeSubida = oldSalary.multiply(valorSubida);

    BigDecimal newSalary = oldSalary.add(porcentajeSubida);

    Query actualizar = session.createQuery("update Emp set sal=:salario where empno= :id");

    actualizar.setParameter("salario",newSalary);
    actualizar.setParameter("id", emp1.getEmpno());
    int res=  query.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(res);
```

}

Pues resulta que a la hora de ejecutar me da la siguiente excepción:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not
>   supported for select queries [From Entity.Emp emp where emp.ename =
>   :nombre]  at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfSelect(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:444)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:347)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
>     at DAO.EmpHelper.incrementarSueldo(EmpHelper.java:67)   at
>   DAO.Main.main(Main.java:38)

Gracias por la ayuda!!!!

Comment: Te falta el SELECT en el primero

Comment: Hola Jonathan, añado el select y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Ok intenta haciendo esto "Select emp.name From Emp emp where emp.name = :nombre"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplicas el método de actualización executeUpdate al objeto query y deberías de aplicarlo al objeto actualizar 
int res = **actualizar**.executeUpdate();